# What's the word for the "back arm" if there is one?

Tags: word-choice

We have the word "forearm" — but what's the other half of the arm called by itself? Does it have a corresponding positional name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In anatomy, it is called the *arm*. “The term forearm is used in anatomy to distinguish it from the arm, a word which is most often used to describe the entire appendage of the upper limb, but in anatomy, technically, it means only the region of the upper arm, whereas the lower ‘arm’ is called the forearm.”[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forearm)

Otherwise, the term used by many people is the *upper arm*:
[image: ²]

Comment: So just the "upper arm", then? Thanks.

Comment: No, what MετάEd actually wrote was that it's just called the "arm" in an anatomical context, but that in general usage it's often called the "upper arm".  That is, in an anatomical context it would technically be incorrect to refer to the upper arm in any way but as the "arm".

Answer (score 10):

*Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary* defines *brachium* as:

> The part of the upper limb from shoulder to elbow.

But as MetaEd states, it is also known as the *upper arm* or just *arm*.

Comment: Yes, but there is front and back to that. Also, upper arm and lower arm.